# Woocommerce Set Billing Address Optional

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I redesigned my Woo checkout page to only show the billing address fields when the Stripe gateway is selected, otherwise if the cheque gateway is selected I do not want to collect their billing address. I have the template finished and the jQuery calls work like a charm.  However, I'm having problems making the billing address fields optional and the shipping address fields required.

Here's what I have so far...I added the following filter to make both address fields not-required:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields');
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $fields ) {
    // add or remove billing fields you do not want
    $keys = array(
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'company',
        'address_1',
        'address_2',
        'city',
        'postcode',
        'state',
        'country'
    );

    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        $fields[$key]['required'] = false;
    }
    return $fields;}
```

I remove this filter when the Stripe gateway is selected using jQuery so that the billing address fields show as required (and re-apply if cheque is selected), this behavior works for the billing address fields.

I now need to make the shipping address fields to show as required, so I tried adding the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'set_shipping_required_fields',9999 );
function set_shipping_required_fields( $fields ) {
    // add or remove billing fields you do not want

    $shipping_keys = array(
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'address_1',
        'city',
        'postcode',
        'state',
    );

    foreach( $shipping_keys as $key ) {
        $fields['shipping']['shipping_'.$key]['required'] = true;

    }
    return $fields;
}
```

This successfully will display the shipping_first_name and shipping_last_name as required, however, the rest of the shipping fields initially render as required, but a split second later will revert back to being optional.  Does anyone have any tips what I'm doing wrong to make the billing address fields optional and shipping address fields required? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

ou should need to use woocommerce_default_address_fields filter hook instead as explained [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/).

```
/ Billing and shipping addresses fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'filter_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );
function filter_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
// Only on checkout page
if( ! is_checkout() ) return $address_fields;

// All field keys in this array
$key_fields = array('country','first_name','last_name','company','address_1','address_2','city','state','postcode');

// Loop through each address fields (billing and shipping)
foreach( $key_fields as $key_field )
    $address_fields[$key_field]['required'] = false;

return $address_fields;
}
```

As billing email and phone are already required by default, if you want them to be not required, you should need this additional code:

```
// For billing email and phone - Make them not required
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'filter_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function filter_billing_fields( $billing_fields ) {
// Only on checkout page
if( ! is_checkout() ) return $billing_fields;

$billing_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
$billing_fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;
return $billing_fields;
```

}

All code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.